# Sharepoint Content-Types 0x01 0x0120

Tags: content-type, custom-list

Was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of info that details what fields these content types add to my custom list.

Was also curious if someone could explain what the Folder element is for in the ContentTypeRef element.

MSDN says "Specifies the relative folder path for the content type's resource folder."

Not sure where this folder is located (assuming the hive) and what resources (the schema perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up the names for some of the basic ones here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896(v=office.14).aspx

With the names, you can go through the UI to Site Settings, and choose "Site Content Types" under the "Galleries" group to see what's defined for your content types.

0x01 is "Item" and is just the root content type for everything else, and has Title by default but can be modified.

0x0120 is "Folder", which has Title and Name and cannot be modified.